# 2 query in 1 model (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I put 2 queries in 1 model?
Here's my code

```
public function declineDec($email,$desc,$prop_id,$fk_table){


        $sql = "INSERT INTO amilyar_applicant_notif (email,notif_fk_table,notif_fk_id,notif_content) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        $data = [$email,$fk_table,$prop_id,$desc];
        $query = $this->db->query($sql,$data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();


        $sql2 ="UPDATE amilyar_properties SET prop_approved = 3 WHERE prop_id = ?";
            $data2 = ($prop_id);
            $this->db->query($sql2, $data2);

        // return $sql;
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Comment: The ```return``` causes your function to exit before it gets to the second statement.  Don't return until you've finished all tasks (By the way, it's generally considered bad practice to have one function do two things, for reasons that are a bit too complex to get into in a short comment)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I dunno what to do bcause it has a function button that will insert and update different tables

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

Try with some modification as below:

```
public function declineDec($email,$desc,$prop_id,$fk_table) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO amilyar_applicant_notif (email,notif_fk_table,notif_fk_id,notif_content) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    $data = [$email,$fk_table,$prop_id,$desc];
    $this->db->query($sql,$data);
    $return['insert'] = $this->db->affected_rows();

    $sql2 ="UPDATE amilyar_properties SET prop_approved = 3 WHERE prop_id = ?";
    $data2 = ($prop_id);
    $this->db->query($sql2, $data2);
    $return['update'] =  $this->db->affected_rows();

    return $return;
}
```

No need of `return` in `return $this->db->affected_rows();` if you have more steps of code to execute.

Comment: can you do `print_r($return);` before `return` statement & confirm there is data.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your query should be like this, and you should use  transactions with databases that support transaction-safe table types

```
public function declineDec($email,$desc,$prop_id,$fk_table)
{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO amilyar_applicant_notif (email,notif_fk_table,notif_fk_id,notif_content) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    $data = [$email,$fk_table,$prop_id,$desc];

    $sql2 = "UPDATE amilyar_properties SET prop_approved = 3 WHERE prop_id = ?";
    $data2 = array($prop_id);


    $this->db->trans_start();

    $this->db->query($sql,$data);
    $this->db->query($sql2, $data2);

    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if($this->db->trans_status())
    {
       return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;  
    }
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html